# How to parse a Formatted String into Date object in Java

Tags: java, date-format

In Java, How to parse "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT" into a Date object, then print the date object out in the same format.

I have tried this:

```
String dStr= "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT"; 
SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("E, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss ZZZ"); 
Date t = ft.parse(dStr); 
System.out.println(t); 
System.out.println(ft.format(t));
```

The result is

```
Wed Jun 05 10:48:12 EST 2013
Wed, 05 Jun 2013 10:48:12 +1000
```

Thanks in advance:

Comment: Does this really produce a 10 hour difference, or is that piece of text bad copied?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux No, it looks like it simply outputs in the local timezone.

Comment: Ah, now I see :) I was confusing with +100 instead of +1000. Which would have still be an hour...

Comment: Here: `System.out.println("Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves your problem:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DateIt{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        String dStr= "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT"; 
        SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"); 
        Date t = ft.parse(dStr); 
        TimeZone gmt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("England/London");
        ft.setTimeZone(gmt);
        System.out.println(t); 
        System.out.println(ft.format(t));
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I use your code, but the result is "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 12:48:12 GMT", which is different to the the input string "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT". Any further suggestion here?

Comment: Does line 7 have 'HH' instead of 'hh'? 'HH' will return the time in 24 hour notation.

Comment: you are right, I was using "hh', after I changed it to "HH", then everything works ok. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have an error, both: `Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT` and `Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT` represent the same time, the first one is GMT (Grenweech) and the second one is the same time in Australia (EST), you just need to configure your time zone properly.

If you want to print the same date in GMT, add this line to your code:

```
ft.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Now, if you also want your date to be printed with the time-zone as "GMT" instead of "+0000", **follow @HewWolff answer** (use zzz instead of ZZZ)

Comment: The question is: does the OP want to output to use the timezone from the original input string, or use a fixed timezone (such as GMT)? I guess [setTimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) is probably part of the solution, but first we need to know the exact problem.

Comment: @Mattias Buelens, I intend to output the original input String in a fixed timezone (such as GMT), What Date and Time Pattern should I used here. The expected result should be the same as "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT".  Thanks.

Comment: @user1304846 use both Hew Wolff answer (to print GMT) and mine (to set the time zone to GMT)

Comment: @morgano, thanks for your advice, and I used the code Clocks provided below and replaced 'z' with "zzz' in his code, the result is "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 12:48:12 GMT", which is different to the the input string "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 00:48:12 GMT". Any further suggestion here?

Comment: @user1304846 Use `HH` instead of `hh` for 24-hours format. Clocks also pointed that out following up on his own answer.

Comment: Thanks, guys, clocks did provide the right solution here and pointed out my mistake. Thanks again, all of you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `zzz` rather than `ZZZ`.  That should help you read/write your time zone as a code rather than a number.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh - I've run into this problem before.

The `SimpleDateFormat.parse(String)` method (I suspect) uses an instance of `Calendar`. This matters for two reasons:

1. You don't know which flavor of Calendar you're dealing with
   (Gregorian? Mayan? Vegan?).
2. Calendar initializes its fields with
   default values that you don't necessarily want set. When the
   SimpleDateFormat calls getTime() on the Calendar instance it created
   to return a Date, that Date will have default field values that
   aren't indicated by the string you submitted to begin with.

These default values are having an impact when the `ft.format(t)` call is made. The only way to solve this problem that I've found is to work with the Calendar class directly (which is entirely  non-trivial, BTW.) I'll try to provide a code sample later when I've got more time. In the mean time, look at `javafx.util.converter.DateStringConverter`.